# Assist in or Assist with

Tags: grammar

I know this sentence is grammatically correct:

> You'll assist him with his homework.

But is this also correct?

> You'll assist him in his homework.

Comment: See [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/48717/difference-between-assist-in-and-assist-with) from ELL. It seems to me that _assist in_ is not appropriate here because the homework is not supposed to be a joint effort, but work assigned to 'him' for which you will only offer incidental help.

Comment: "assist in" is usually followed by a gerund, e.g. "assist him in doing his homework"